# Duplicate rows of data in python using while loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's the code I am using to create a simple amortization table. Using the dataframes though it replicates the column name when I print the dataframe:

```
import numpy
import pandas
homeprice = 500000
LoanAmt = 500000
term = 30
interestrate = 0.0325
i= 1
Interestonlyterm = 5
while i<=term:
if i <= Interestonlyterm:
    Payment = round(LoanAmt * interestrate / 12, 2)
    Endingbalance = LoanAmt
    Priorbalance = Endingbalance
    Interestpaid = Payment * 12
    Principalpaid = 0
    Annualpayment = Payment*12
else:
    Payment = round(numpy.pmt(interestrate / 12, (term - Interestonlyterm) * 12, - LoanAmt, 0, 0), 2)
    if i == 1:
        Priorbalance = LoanAmt
    else:
        Priorbalance = round(numpy.pv(interestrate / 12, (term - i + 1) * 12, Payment, 0, 0) * -1, 2)
    Endingbalance = round(numpy.pv(interestrate/12, (term-i)*12, Payment, 0, 0)*-1, 2)
    Principalpaid = round((Priorbalance-Endingbalance), 2)
    Interestpaid = round((Payment* 12 - Principalpaid), 2)
    Annualpayment = round(Payment*12, 2)

data = [Principalpaid]
df = pandas.DataFrame(data, index=[i], columns=['Principal Paid'])
print(df)


i=i+1
```

Comment: looks like some port of source code is missing. Can you post a bigger part of your case please?

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a variable (`paid_list` for example) contains the list of paid information during the while-loop, and then just create the dataframe once in the end, I don't think you need multiple dataframes which you created one in each iteration

```
paid_list = list()
while i<=term:
  if i <= Interestonlyterm:
    Payment = round(LoanAmt * interestrate / 12, 2)
    Endingbalance = LoanAmt
    Priorbalance = Endingbalance
    Interestpaid = Payment * 12
    Principalpaid = 0
    Annualpayment = Payment*12
  else:
    Payment = round(numpy.pmt(interestrate / 12, (term - Interestonlyterm) * 12, - LoanAmt, 0, 0), 2)
    if i == 1:
        Priorbalance = LoanAmt
    else:
        Priorbalance = round(numpy.pv(interestrate / 12, (term - i + 1) * 12, Payment, 0, 0) * -1, 2)
    Endingbalance = round(numpy.pv(interestrate/12, (term-i)*12, Payment, 0, 0)*-1, 2)
    Principalpaid = round((Priorbalance-Endingbalance), 2)
    Interestpaid = round((Payment* 12 - Principalpaid), 2)
    Annualpayment = round(Payment*12, 2)
  paid_list += [Principalpaid]


df = pandas.DataFrame({'Principal Paid': paid_list}) 
print(df)
```

Comment: thanks Paul, but I need to print the entire amortization table. If I insert your code inside the loop, then when I print it out, it duplicates the 'Principal Paid' text on every other line

Comment: I found your updated code now, I did some changes accordingly. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: with every run of the while loop, it's printing the table as such. We want to print the table only once:                                                                                 
      Principal Paid
0               0
   Principal Paid
0               0
1               0
   Principal Paid
0               0
1               0
2               0